# Adding to a mutable type as if it was immutable (orderlessly)

Tags: c#, arrays, immutability

I'm building an object on form:

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(row => new Something
  {
    Field = row["field1"] as int?,
    Bunch = GetBunch(index)
  });
```

with *GetBunch()* as follows.

```
private IList GetBunch(int index) { ... }
```

It works as supposed to. Now, we've noticed that we need to add an additional element to the array that we put into *Bunch*. For a range of reasons, it's not an option to change the signature of the method, nor is it feasible to add the extra element inside it.

I tried to add the extra thingy like so:

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(row => new Something
  {
    Field = row["field1"] as int?,
    Bunch = GetBunch(index).Add(new Thingy() { ... })
  });
```

but it didn't work because *Add()* doesn't return the original array with the new element in it. It returns an *int*. If the original object would be immutable, the result of *Add()* would be what I wish but, apparently, it isn't.

Is it possible to immutabilize an mutable object? If not (because I'm fairly certain it's not), how can I handle this easily? (Easily = without storing the created thing and then accessing it and adding an element to *Bunch* property's array.)

NB, the order of the result is of no importance in this case. The proper type would be *Bag* of some kind but I'm hand-tied by the pre-existing design.

Comment: I'm not sure that mutability and immutability is really that important here. I see where you are coming from that with immutable objects then adding an item will by necessity involve returning a new object but that doesn't mean that this behaviour is solely used by immutable objects. You could easily create any object that returned itself from method calls. That isn't obviously useful in solving your problem but all the talk of wanting to make a mutable object immutable confused the heck out of me when reading the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.Select(row => {
                  var list = GetBunch(index);
                  list.Add(new Thingy() { ... });
                  return new SomeThing 
                         {
                            Field = row["field1"] as int?,
                            Bunch = list
                         };
                });
```

As @Chris noted in the comments you can use a lambda statement, you don't necessarily need to use lamda expression.You can do whatever you want inside of the blocks since it's just a method that takes a `DataRow` and returns `SomeThing`.

Comment: The key thing here being that a lambda can have a block of code and not just a single item as its body.

Comment: @Chris yes and this is called lamda statement rather than lambda expression

Comment: +1. If you have one-off case this is approach to take, if such pattern repeats multiple times in code than consider refactoring into helper methods. I.e. as extension to "add item to this list" covered in my answer or wrapping `GetBunch` into helper that adds more.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Single location. In the next version of the API, it'll be reworked completely.

Comment: @Selman22: Ah, I hadn't realised it had a slightly different name. That makes it much easier to refer to. :) Mainly I was just wanting to highlight to the OP the feature that your answer took advantage of since it might not have been clear at a glance at your code.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to good Selman22's answer: create helper extension method that would let you add to result of `GetBunch()` without need to wrap it in lambda inline:

```
static class MyListExtenstions
{
  static IList AddToList<T>(this IList list, T item)
  {
    list.Add(item);
    return list;
  }
}
```

And use it inline:

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(row => new Something
     {
         Field = row["field1"] as int?,
         Bunch = GetBunch(index).AddToList(new Thingy() { ... })
     });
```

One more LINQ approach that creates more intermediate objects, but would work on immutable (meaning adding items throws exception) list:

If you want to have method that can be used for chaining you can use `IEnumerable<T>.Concat()` (and than `.ToList()` in your case). This approach will give you new list and would be useful if result of `GetBunch` is :

```
 GetBunch(index)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(new Thingy() { ... }, 1))
    .ToList()
```

NOTE: If your `GetBunch` would return generic `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` than you can use helper methods of `Enumerable` (like `.Concat()`). Since it returns non-generic version you need to convert it to generic variant with something like `Enumerable.Cast` or cast to generic interface to use LINQ approach. You need to know what actual type is there OR what type of items should be returned.

```
 GetBunch(index).Cast<object>()
 GetBunch(index) as IList<Thingy>
```

Comment: Weird. I don't get *Concat* nor *Union* from intellisense there... Is it because I'm using *IList*?! It shouldn't be, right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten - I've inlined the answer to the comment - indeed you have non-generic `IList` which prevents most LINQ methods to be used.

Comment: And I'm very opposed to not using generic types. However, I'm bound to follow the directions of the other programmer who thinks it's nicer to go that way because "it works good and is shorter so it must be better and the type can be inferred anyway and you can see it in the debug so what's the difference bite me".

Answer (score 0):

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new Something
    {
        Field = row["field1"] as int?,
        Bunch = GetBunch(index).Union(x => 
            new[] { new Thingy() { ... } }
            ).ToList()
    });
```

Comment: `Union` is set operation and does not guarantee order. `Concat` is better one in most regular cases (sample in my answer).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In fact, the order isn't an issue here. However, as I stated in my other comment, I don't get *Union* from intellisense here. Weird indeed.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - consider updating post with "order not important" comment as it makes this answer usable too.

Comment: @KonradViltersten you have non-generic list (`IList`) while all LINQ methods expect `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e. `IList<T>`) and hence you will not get intellisence. I'll update my answer with that info.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Are you certain? I thought that by **not** mentioning that, it's implied that the order isn't required. I'm afraid that someone else might request to add even more parameters that **aren't** required. Or is, perhaps, it so common to need the order to be respected that it calls for an explicit mentioning? What do you think? What do others think?

Comment: @KonradViltersten `IList`/`IList<T>` actually strongly imply importance of the order as they represent not only ordered but also indexable collections. Even plain `IEnumerable<T>` would not *imply* that unordered set is ok. It defines order to and viewed as ordered sequence by many people, even if it commonly used to return unordered sets like result of set operations (`Union`, `Distinct`) or database queries. (Side note: that's why I've only suggested to "consider" edit - your question and you decide what is important and what is not)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov And I do appreciate the **suggestion**. I just wasn't sure if it applied, as I didn't see any motivation for it. Now, that you've pointed out the implication I see that I missed it and I stand (happily) corrected. The edition will take place shortly. Very good and polite explanation, by the way. We need more of this tone at SO. :)